# Как делать запросы к баз данных на изменение из другого процесса в Django?

Tags: django, многопоточность, postgresql, python-2.x, multiprocessing

Запускается некая задача в отдельном процессе, где в бесконечном цикле нужно производить некоторые действия и результат записать в БД. При первом прходе цикла отрабатывает, а затем выкидывает исключение:

**DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.**

Как реализовать запись в БД в другом процессе в Django?

```
_process = Process(target=start_process, args=(message,id))
_process.start()

def start_process(message,id):
    while True:
        ...
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE tasks SET exemplar=%s WHERE id_tsk=%s;""", [exemplar, id])
        cursor.close()
        ...
        sleep(100)
```

Comment: Django проектировался строго для последовательного выполнения. Используйте для фоновых задач Celery.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А Celery работает с ActiveMQ?

Comment: Интересно, что код работает при создании процесса в методе ready(), запускающегося при инициализации сервера, и соединение к БД не падает. Может можно для такой небольшой задачи костылик придумать?

Comment: Проверьте логи постгреса, может оно обваливается из-за ошибки синтаксиса, например, или ещё чего

Answer (score 1):

Если django используется для отображения данных, то достаточно положить рядом файл python который будет выполнять всю работу по записи данных в базу. Данный файл может быть и многопоточным (на сколько позволяет интерпретатор).

Если нужны какие-то django специфичные действия, достаточно импортировать только нужное.